# What's the reason for C standard to consider const-ness recursively?

Tags: design, c

The C99 standard says in 6.5.16:2:

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left
>   operand.

and in 6.3.2.1:1:

> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, does
>   not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type, and
>   if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
>   recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or
>   unions) with a const-qualified type.

Now, let's consider a non-`const` `struct` with a `const` field.

```
typedef struct S_s {
    const int _a;
} S_t;
```

By standard, the following code is undefined behavior (UB):

```
S_t s1;
S_t s2 = { ._a = 2 };
s1 = s2;
```

The semantic problem with this is that the enclosing entity (`struct`) should be considered writable (non-read-only), judging by the declared type of the entity (`S_t s1`), but should not be considered writable by the wording of standard (the 2 clauses on the top) because of `const` field `_a`. The Standard makes it unclear for a programmer reading the code that the assignment is actually a UB, because it's impossible to tell that w/o the definition of `struct S_s ... S_t` type.

Moreover, the read-only access to the field is only enforced syntactically anyway. There's no way some `const` fields of non-`const` `struct` are going really be placed to read-only storage. But such wording of standard outlaws the code which deliberately casts away the `const` qualifier of fields in accessor procedures of these fields, like so ([Is it a good idea to const-qualify the fields of structure in C?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222457/is-it-a-good-idea-to-const-qualify-the-fields-of-structure-in-c)):

**(*)**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct S_s {
    const int _a;
} S_t;

S_t *
create_S(void) {
    return calloc(sizeof(S_t), 1);
}

void
destroy_S(S_t *s) {
    free(s);
}

const int
get_S_a(const S_t *s) {
    return s->_a;
}

void
set_S_a(S_t *s, const int a) {
    int *a_p = (int *)&s->_a;
    *a_p = a;
}

int
main(void) {
    S_t s1;
    // s1._a = 5; // Error
    set_S_a(&s1, 5); // OK
    S_t *s2 = create_S();
    // s2->_a = 8; // Error
    set_S_a(s2, 8); // OK

    printf("s1.a == %d\n", get_S_a(&s1));
    printf("s2->a == %d\n", get_S_a(s2));

    destroy_S(s2);
}
```

So, for some reason, for an entire `struct` to be read-only it's enough to declare it `const`

```
const S_t s3;
```

But for an entire `struct` to be non-read-only it's not enough to declare it w/o `const`.

What I think would be better, is either:

1. To constrain the creation of non-`const` structures with `const` fields, and issue a diagnostic in such a case. That would make it clear that the `struct` containing read-only fields is read-only itself.
2. To define the behavior in case of write to a `const` field belonging to a non-`const` struct as to make the code above **(*)** compliant to the Standard.

Otherwise the behavior is not consistent and hard to understand.

So, what's the reason for C Standard to consider `const`-ness recursively, as it puts it?

Comment: To be honest, I don't see a question in there.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau edited to add the question stated in the topic in the end of the body

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, what's the reason for C Standard to consider const-ness recursively, as it puts it?

From a type perspective alone, not doing so would be unsound (in other words: terribly broken and intentionally unreliable).

And that's because of what "=" means on a struct: it is a recursive assignment. It follows that eventually you have a `s1._a = <value>` happening "inside the typing rules". If the standard allows this for "nested" `const` fields, its adding a serious inconsistency in its type system definition as an explicit contradiction (might as well throw the `const` feature away, as it just became useless and unreliable by its very definition).

Your solution (1), as far as I understand it, is unnecessarily forcing the entire structure to be `const` whenever one of its fields is `const`. In this way, `s1._b = b` would be illegal for a non-const `._b` field on a non-const `s1` containing a `const a`.

Comment: Well. `C` barely has a sound type system (more like a bunch of corner cases strapped onto each other over the course of years). Besides, the other way to put the assignment to a `struct` is `memcpy(s_dest, s_src, sizeof(S_t))`. And I'm pretty sure it's the actual way it's implemented. And in such case even existing "type system" doesn't prohibit you doing that.

Comment: Very true. I hope I did not imply that C's type system is sound, only that deliberately making a specific semantics unsound deliberately defeats it. Moreover, though C's type system is not strongly enforced, the ways to breach it are often explicit (pointers, indirect access, casts) -- even though its effects are frequently implicit and hard to track. Thus, having explicit "fences" to breach them informs better than having a contradiction in the definitions themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that read-only fields are read-only. No big surprise there.

You're mistakenly assuming that the only effect is on placement in ROM, which indeed is impossible when there are adjacent non-const fields. In reality, optimizers may assume `const` expressions are not written to, and optimize based on that. Of course that assumption doesn't hold when non-const aliases exist.

Your solution (1) breaks existing legal and reasonable code. That won't happen. Your solution (2) pretty much removes the meaning of `const` on members. While this won't break existing code, it seems to lack a rationale.

Comment: I'm 90% sure optimizers *may not* assume that `const` fields are not written to, because you always can use `memset` or `memcpy`, and that would even be compliant to the Standard. (1) can be implemented as, at the very least, additional warning, enabled by a flag. (2)'s rationale is that, well, exactly — there's no way a component of `struct` can be considered non-writable when the entire structure *is* writable.

Comment: An "optional diagnostic determined by a flag" would be a unique requirement for the Standard to demand. Besides, setting the flag would still break existing code, so in effect nobody would bother with the flag and it would be a dead end. As for (2), 6.3.2.1:1 specifies exactly the opposite: the entire structure is _non-writeable_ whenever one component is. However, _other components_ may still be writeable. Cf. C++ which defines also `operator=` in terms of the members, and therefore doesn't define a `operator=` when one member is `const`. C and C++ are still compatible here.

Comment: @constantius - The fact that you CAN do something to deliberately get around the constness of a member is NOT a reason for the optimizer to ignore that constness. You CAN cast away constness inside of a function, allowing you to change stuff. But the optimizer in the calling context is still allowed to assume you won't. Constness is useful for the programmer, but it's also a god-send for the optimizer in some cases.

Comment: Then why a non-writable structure is allowed to be overwritten with i.e. `memcpy`? As for other reasons — ok, it's legacy, but why was it done in such way in the first place?

Comment: I can "break" the optimizer with absolutely standard compliant code by using `memcpy`. And optimizer has to be conservative because, well, alias analysis in C compilers just isn't quite "working all the time reliably".

Comment: I'm still wondering if your comment about `memcpy` is right. AFACIT John Bode's quote in your other question is right: your code writes to a const-qualified object and therefore is NOT standard complaint, end of discussion.

Comment: @constantius: It's "allowed" only in the sense that the compiler isn't required to diagnose an attempt to do it. The behavior is undefined. `const int n = 42; (*(int*)&n) ++; printf("%d\n", n);` may print `42`, or `43`, or a suffusion of yellow.

Comment: @MSalters Jogn Bode's quote only refers to attempts to modify objects which have `const`-qualified types *themselves*.